# How do the color configurations of the fish shell and IntelliJ IDE play together?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, fish

I've currently set my IntelliJ color scheme to 'Solarized Dark' (which is pretty similar to the default 'Darcula') and am using the fish shell. Unfortunately it is hard to read the log output where it gives the numbers of lines which don't compile, as pictured below. I already tried to tweak my IntelliJ configuration, but couldn't find any reference to the dark blue color, and fish shows different colors in iTerm - where does it come from?

[image: log output]

Comment: This isn't fish output. Fish doesn't set these colors. I'm guessing this is `rustc`.

Comment: I would consider this to be a bug in the Solarized Dark palette, tbh - rustc simply [colors line numbers blue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/0e7915d11f6888f005e78c2358fcdc48ff655753/compiler/rustc_errors/src/emitter.rs#L2437), and "blue" is unreadable against the background.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be an IntelliJ configuration issue. The general color scheme setting does not affect the console font colors, just the console background, which might improve the readability if it provides a light background. This is the setting for which I was looking for so long: 'Editor -> Color Scheme -> General -> Hyperlinks -> Reference -> Foreground'